# Primitives revisited

Tags: performance, primitive, forth

I am well aware of Stack Overflow question *[What are the primitive Forth operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/407987)*, but it doesn't really address my question. I am looking not for the *minimal* but rather *practical* set of primitives.

Recently I faced a problem which required frequently sorting quite large arrays, and the performance became critical. A [naive qsort](http://en.literateprograms.org/Quicksort_%28Forth%29) benchmarked at 20. Porting a heavily (algorithmically) optimized STL version gain me benchmark 16. Native C++ laughed at me from benchmark 3. Oh well.

Finally I bit a bullet and implemented `EXCH ( a1 a2 -- a1 a2 )` and non-destructive compares `( n1 n2 -- n1 n2 flag )` as primitives. The results were amazing - three-fold performance gain. Still not C++, but way closer.

Why doesn't standard Forth have them out of the box?

PS: the benchmark is *(execution time, nsec)/(n log n)*

Comment: What hardware is it running on?

Comment: @PeterMortensen amd64

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that `EXCH` is not a part of standard Forth simply because it is obscure enough that you are probably better off writing your own if you need it.

I would imagine that non-destructive compares would count as a violation of the general principles of Forth, specifically that words should consume their arguments. If you want to keep the arguments you have to explicitly create a copy.

I don't know enough about implementations to say what sort of performance impact it has, but for most applications

```
: non-destructive-> 2dup > ;
```

would make sense and work well enough.

I realise that this is a slightly evasive answer, but I suspect that it is that way because from what I have read the choices behind what words should constitute a standard Forth were not made to optimise execution speed.

Answer (score 2):

The effect of such changes depend heavily on the quality of your Forth system. Obviously the worse the compiler is, the more effect well-thought out changes will have. On the other hand, it is more difficult to shave off 1 cycle of 4, than 10 cycles of 40. This means that at some point high-level rewrites do not pay off anymore (unless you are a compiler writer :-)

There are of course tricks with multi-threading and special CPU instructions that one might experiment with.

To see where you are, it would be helpful if you could provide actual code and timings on a real system.